# C++ End a do while loop after reaching the end of input

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a program that translates input into its binary form using C++. However i'm having a bit of problem with the do-while loop portion that continues to translate each additional input. The condition for the do-while loop is messed up so the output becomes an infinite loop.

```
do{
   cin>>number;
   if (number<0)
      cout<< number<< " (base 10) is not a positive integer"<<endl;
   else if (number==0) 
      cout<< number<< " (base 10) = 0 (base 2) ";
   else {
      binary= binaryConverter(number);
      cout<< number << " (base 10) =";
      cout<< binary << " (base 2)";
   }
   cout<< endl;
}while(????);
```

Comment: What's the condition that's supposed to actually end it? If the user stops inputing?

Comment: Why do people tag things like this C?

Answer (score 3):

This will loop till termination signal is received (like CTRL-C), then stream is terminated

```
while(cin >> number)
```

Comment: @user1344877 If this answer works for you, then you should consider "accepting" it by clicking the green check mark. That will indicate that this is the officially accepted answer for your question and will give victor.t some extra reputation. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/154119)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that such a loop will exit gracefully when it receives an end-of-file indication (from a console: CTRL-D or CTRL-Z, depending upon environment.)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical C++ input loop looks like this:

```
ItemType item;
while ( input_stream >> item ) {
   // Do something with item, for example:
   //   std::cout << item;  or,
   //   container.push_back(item);  or,
   //   sum += item;  or whatever.
}
```

That sort of loop will run exactly once per input item, will stop at end-of-file (whether it is the end of a disk file or EOF signaled from the console). It will also stop as soon as the input no longer comports to the format of an item (for example, if `ItemType` is `int` and the input has the letter Q in it.)

Specifically, one should *never* use `.eof()` or `.good()` as a loop condition. One should hardly ever use a `do-while` as the input loop.

In your case, the loop should look like:

```
while(std::cin >> number) {
  std::cin>>number;
  if (number<0)
    std::cout<< number<< " (base 10) is not a positive integer";
  else if (number==0) 
    std::cout<< number<< " (base 10) = 0 (base 2) ";
  else {
    binary= binaryConverter(number);
    std::cout<< number << " (base 10) =";
    std::cout<< binary << " (base 2)";
  }
  std::cout<< "\n";
}
```

<sup>P.s. I modified your code to conform to two other widely-adopted standards: never say `using namespace std;` and never say `std::endl` when you mean `'\n'`.</sup>